# How to trigger a Lambda function on Kinesis with number of messages

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have an AWS Lambda function that triggers on every Kinesis record when it comes into Kinesis. However, I want to trigger the Lambda function with a specific number of  messages.

For example, I want to trigger the Lambda function with 5 messages rather than 1.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the maximum number of records you want to receive by using the `Limit` parameter of the `GetRecords` request but the actual number of messages you receive may be less than this value.  There is no way to control that.  It depends mainly on the volume of records coming into the stream.